# What's wrong with this tcpdump syntax?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

```
sudo tcpdump -i ath1 -s 0 -nne "(type mgt and subtype beacon)"
```

Can anyone help me? I was following a tutorial at http://wiki.secarmour.com/2013/09/capture-wireless-traffic.html but seems I got something wrong. The error I get is "syntax" error.

Comment: What does `tcpdump -h` print?

Comment: @GuyHarris http://imgur.com/N61jV1a

Comment: That's *all* it printed?  It didn't print anything saying "tcpdump version ..." or "libpcap version ..."?  *That's* the information I need - tcpdump and libpcap version numbers, to see whether you have an old version of libpcap that didn't support those 802.11 filters.

Comment: that is all sadly